# Optimal way to reverse this serialization

Tags: java, csv, serialization, deserialization

I've written the following method to serialize an object and write it to a .csv file: it works well.

```
    public static void serializeAsCSV(String path, Book book) throws IOException {
        Path filePath = Paths.get(path); //create a new path object, passing the path
        byte[] strToBytes = book.prettyPrintCSV().getBytes();//converts the String to bytes
        Files.write(filePath, strToBytes); //writes the bytes to the file
```

I suppose I don't understand it fully because I'm having trouble writing the method to deserialize the .csv file into an object.

this is what I have currently:

```
    public static void deserializeFromCSV(String path, Book book) throws IOException {
        List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("books.csv"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                records.add(Arrays.asList(values));
                records.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }
```

main method which calls serialize/deserialize:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Book book = new Book("Donald", "Male", "Brown"); //create a new instance of Book
        System.out.println(book.prettyPrintCSV()); //output the String values of new Book instance, moves to new line
        Book.serializeAsCSV("books.csv", book); //calls the serializeAsCSV method, passing the path and the book object
        Book.deserializeFromCSV("books.csv", book); //calls the deserializeFromCSV method, passing the path
    }
```

please ignore the attributes which don't have anything to do with books. I changed the class from "Baby" to "Book" and I need to refactor.

Comment: Can you specify what did not work?

Comment: Show us `prettyPrintCSV`. It is the method which does actual serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new instances of books for every line:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    records.add(new Book(values[0], values[1],values[2]));
}
```

Also you should return your list at the end and why you have the parameter `book` for the desirialize method?
Also the List makes no sence, you only serialize only one book

Comment: It is not csv parser. Id doesn't work with escaping. It is always better to use existing library.